# Toggle show more or less on particular children of div

Tags: javascript

I'm actually trying to toggle particular div:nth-child on an Elementor accordion. Though I managed to code it in Javascript, I know there's a shorter and cleaner way to loop this. Please help.

```css
.acc-sec :nth-child(5), :nth-child(6), :nth-child(7) {
    display: none;
}
#acc-more {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script>
function showMore() {
    if (document.querySelector("a").innerHTML == "Show more") {
        var shownth5 = document.querySelector(".acc-sec :nth-child(5)");
        shownth5.style.display = "block";    
        var shownth6 = document.querySelector(".acc-sec :nth-child(6)");
        shownth6.style.display = "block";  
        var shownth7 = document.querySelector(".acc-sec :nth-child(7)");
        shownth7.style.display = "block";  
        document.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "Show less";
        document.querySelector("a").addEventListener('click', showLess);     
    } else {
        showLess();
    }
}
function showLess() {
    if (document.querySelector("a").innerHTML == "Show less") {        
        var shownth5 = document.querySelector(".acc-sec :nth-child(5)");
        shownth5.style.display = "none";    
        var shownth6 = document.querySelector(".acc-sec :nth-child(6)");
        shownth6.style.display = "none";  
        var shownth7 = document.querySelector(".acc-sec :nth-child(7)");
        shownth7.style.display = "none";  
        document.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "Show more";
        document.querySelector("a").addEventListener('click', showMore);         
    }else {
        showMore();
    }   
}
</script>
<div class="acc-sec" onload="loop()">
        <div>This is the first div.</div>
        <div>This is the second div.</div>
        <div>This is the third div.</div>
        <div>This is the fourth div.</div>
        <div id="hidden1">This is the fifth div.</div>
        <div id="hidden2">This is the sixth div.</div>
        <div id="hidden3">This is the seventh div.</div>
        <a id="acc-more" onclick="showMore()">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS is wrong, the comma is not a scoped separator so `, :nth-child(6)` means “the sixth child of the whole document” not “the sixth child of .acc-sec”

Comment: Also, your `addEventListener` will add multiple click listeners executing the same code which will result in behavior you don't expect, either call `removeEventListener` before adding the new one or assign to `onclick`

Comment: Last but not least, if your HTML structure is static just use the [details element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp)

Comment: Not actually. The CSS is correct for the initial state of the div.

Comment: Yah you're right. Changed it to:
```
.acc-sec :nth-child(8), .acc-sec :nth-child(9), .acc-sec :nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a much easier way in doing this.

made small changes and added `class` instead of `id` as it will create less code.

have a look below

```js
    document.querySelectorAll(".acc-more").forEach(el=>{
     const hidden= el.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
     el.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
      hidden.forEach(h=> h.classList.toggle("hidden")) 
      if (hidden[0].classList.contains("hidden"))
          el.innerHTML = "Show more";
        else el.innerHTML = "Show less";
     });
    });
```

```css
    .acc-sec .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    #acc-more {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="acc-sec">
            <div>This is the first div.</div>
            <div>This is the second div.</div>
            <div>This is the third div.</div>
            <div>This is the fourth div.</div>
            <div class="hidden">This is the fifth div.</div>
            <div class="hidden">This is the sixth div.</div>
            <div class="hidden">This is the seventh div.</div>
            <a class="acc-more" >Show more</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, the link should change to 'show less' though once toggled

Comment: You are right, I just updated the answer and now it show show less and more

Answer (score 0):

****Updating*** [@Alen.toma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4828524/alen-toma) js snippet.

Using short-hand `if-else` for ***changing*** the `innerText` of the link just after toggling the `hidden` class. Accept the answer if it helps.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".acc-more").forEach(el => {
  const hidden = el.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".hidden")
  const showMoreLess = document.querySelector(".acc-more")
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hidden.forEach(h => h.classList.toggle("hidden"))
    showMoreLess.innerText === "Show more" ? showMoreLess.innerText = "Show less" : showMoreLess.innerText = "Show more"
    console.log(showMoreLess)
  });
});
```

```css
.acc-sec .hidden {
  display: none;
}

#acc-more {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="acc-sec">
  <div>This is the first div.</div>
  <div>This is the second div.</div>
  <div>This is the third div.</div>
  <div>This is the fourth div.</div>
  <div class="hidden">This is the fifth div.</div>
  <div class="hidden">This is the sixth div.</div>
  <div class="hidden">This is the seventh div.</div>
  <a class="acc-more">Show more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can omit the `console.log(showMoreLess)` line. That's just for _debugging_.

Comment: When 'Show less' is clicked, the divs don't go back to initial state.

Comment: Are you kidding? Please click `Run code snippet` and then click `Full page` for a full page view and click on the `Show more` link. Each `<div>` containing a `hidden` class will expand, and the text of `<a>` will change to `Show less` (check the console). Clicking again on `Show less` will bring everything back to its initial state. I have re-tested my code snippet 5-times and receiving the results you want! But why it's not working for you? I've no idea.

Comment: It's OK. You're Welcome . Regards,